# ConfigParser getting value from INI file with section and subsection as shown below

Tags: python, ini, configparser

I have a following type of INI file

```
[section1][subsection1]
port=989
[section1][subsection2]
somethign=somethign
```

I am using ConfigParser of Python to parse the INI file but I am not able to figure it out on how to get the data from the above kinda INI file.

the below code is for getting the value when INI file is like

```
[section1]
port=908
[section2]
ss=ss

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read(INI_File)
mIp =  config.get('section1','port')
```

Please don't suggest me to change the INI file format :)

thank you

Answer (score 5):

It appears that ConfigParser ignores subsections.  If you absolutely need subsections, you may want to try alternative parsers such as ConfigObj ([PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/configobj/), [tutorial](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/configobj.shtml))

And here is an answer to an older question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3008051/49412

Comment: I tried ConfigObj but unfortunately it only parses the INI files in the below format 

`[section]
   [[subsection]]
     blah=1`

Comment: Thank you for sharing ConfigObj! It's exactly what I was looking for!