# Python - ConfigParser - .ini file too large?

Tags: python, ini, configparser

This is my first question on stackoverflow and I have only been involved with python for a short time, but I have a problem with reading an .ini file and I cannot find the answer anywhere.

This is a small piece of my current code:

```
import configparser 
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.sections()
config.read("filename.ini")
print(config.sections)
```

The script runs, but it does not print the names of the sections in my .ini file. I have waited for more than 15 min, but I still receive nothing. Could it be that the file is too large? It is 32.628 KB and I have to do the same thing multiple times so I was hoping I could automate it.

I hope someone can help me out

Comment: Please attach your ini file structure

Comment: Its more likely you have some kind of recursion in your file, e.g. using a section within itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you want to parse a normal INI file, this should be the source code for it (which your file probably does not follow, so you might consider following this format):

```
[section_1]
section_1_1: test0
section_1_2: test1
section_1_3: test3

[section_2]
section_2_1: test0
section_2_2: test1
section_2_3: test3
```

Your code should work - with a small adjustment

```
from configparser import ConfigParser 
config = ConfigParser()
config.sections()
config.read("conf.ini")
print(config.sections())
for section in config.sections():
    for option in config.options(section):
        print("Option: {} in section: {}".format(option, section))
```

If you have a complex INI file (with sub sections) - then ConfigParser won't be able to help you here, and you'll need another parser for that, check this:
[ConfigParser getting value from INI file with section and subsection as shown below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350462/configparser-getting-value-from-ini-file-with-section-and-subsection-as-shown-be)